# Heroku Migrations and Rake Tasks all but grind to a halt after ~10k SQL writes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've notice that my Migrations and Rake Tasks basically stop after about ~10k new records created. Has anyone else noticed this issue? Is Heroku doing some throttling?

**Any advice other than breaking the Migration/Rake Task into smaller pieces?**

**Is this a known issue with Heroku?**

*Details:*

- Rails 3.1.10 app
- Heroku Cedar
- Logging to console is disable, but I print a '.' for every write

*Thoughts:*
At first I thought it was too many SQL statements printed out over the wire, slowing down the connection or some bad magic like that. But since I disabled logging, nothing's changed. Also, it happens agnostically of the code -- I notice it when I create thousands of any type of record.

### Edit

I'm creating `Suggestion` records in a loop which invokes this code:

```
# in suggestable.rb
# Suggestable polymorphically represents objects which can be suggested

has_many :parent_suggestions, class_name: 'Suggestion', as: :suggestable, dependent: :destroy

# create Suggestion for this suggestable / suggestee
def suggest_to!(suggestee, conf=0)
  get_parent_suggestion_for(suggestee) || 
    parent_suggestions.create(suggestable: self, confidence: conf, suggestee: suggestee)
end
```

Comment: How are you creating them, and what do your logs say? More info please

Comment: @ctshryock my logs (before being disabled) were just printing a ton of SQL: SELECTS (for User, a Suggestable, Suggestion), INSERT (a Suggestion) and repeat 10k+ times. There are no errors. It's just like my app is running out of memory or being throttled or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the newly created (and instantiated) suggestions are all in an association of an object in the loop that is creating them, then they won't get garbage collected. You could try periodically reloading the root object to free the references.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! I'm pretty sure this is the issue.